# Proper way to link Ajax URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my plugin, I have some jQuery-Ajax code that processes form data and adds it to the database as soon as the button is clicked. Since many people have a different path to their plugin folder, I was wondering if there was anyway to standardize the URL that points to the data processing PHP file. See my example below:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "url_to_php_file_path.php",
   data: data,
   cache: false,
   success: function() {
      alert.("added");
   }
});
```

Comment: I would suggest offering an option in your plugin for them to explicitly set the path of the PHP code when using your plugin.

Comment: @crush I would definitely NOT recommend to do that. Please see my detailed answer.

Comment: @usernotfound No, I agree. I didn't realize this was for WordPress at the time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Figuring out the target URL

In WordPress, all AJAX requests must be made to the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

You should not make an AJAX request directly to a file residing in the plugin or theme directory.

Also, do not hard-code the above URL, instead you should use the following function to construct the URL:

```
<script>
    ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

Alternatively to the above, you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), but this is not required, the above is fine too.

Note: Don't worry about the "admin" part, this URL is the correct one to use for all users, including non-logged-in (guest) users.

## Tell WordPress what function to use for your AJAX request

You need to let WordPress know which function should process your AJAX request.

For that purpose you'll create a custom function, and register it using the `wp_ajax_*` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` hooks:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mycustomfunc', 'mycustomfunc'); // Logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mycustomfunc', 'mycustomfunc'); // Guest users
function mycustomfunc() {

    $whatever = esc_html($_POST['whatever']);
    echo 'It works: '.$whatever;
    exit; // This is required to end AJAX requests properly.
}
```

## Don't forget to specify "mycustomfunc" in the AJAX request too

Finally, here is how you would make a proper AJAX request:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var my_data = {
            action: 'mycustomfunc', // This is required so WordPress knows which func to use
            whatever: "yes it is" // Post any variables you want here
        };

        jQuery.post(ajax_url, my_data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

---

## Combine it all

If you had to put it all into one file, here's how you'd do it:

```
// Register my custom function for AJAX processing
add_action('wp_ajax_mycustomfunc', 'mycustomfunc'); // Logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mycustomfunc', 'mycustomfunc'); // Guest users
function mycustomfunc() {

    $whatever = esc_html($_POST['whatever']);
    echo 'It works: '.$whatever;
    exit; // This is required to end AJAX requests properly.
}


// Inline JavaScript
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_inline_js');
function my_inline_js() { ?>

    <script>
        // Set the "ajax_url" variable available globally
        ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

        // Make your AJAX request on document ready:
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var my_data = {
                    action: 'mycustomfunc', // This is required so WordPress knows which func to use
                    whatever: "yes it is" // Post any variables you want here
                };

                $.post(ajax_url, my_data, function(response) { // This will make an AJAX request upon page load
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <?php
}
```

Note: For the `ajax_url` part, you could use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) instead of setting it manually, but it is less flexible as it requires to specify an existing enqueued script, which you might not have.

Note: Also, for outputting inline JavaScript manually into a page, the `wp_footer` hook is the correct one to use. If using [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) then you would use the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook instead.

Comment: I used admin_head for the inline action's hook since it didn't work with the footer.

Comment: @AndreYonadam if it doesn't work with [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) (or [`in_admin_footer`](http://goo.gl/MZVTNW) for the backend)  then it is likely because your script is located **before** the `ajax_url` variable is set. To fix this you can either call your script on `$(document).ready()`, or either make sure that `ajax_url` variable is set _before_ your script is included, for example by using the [`wp_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) (or [`admin_head`](http://goo.gl/kTnoGy) for the backend) hook.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, all ajax calls should be registered through `wp_ajax`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_something', 'add_something');
```

This code should be in your plugin file, along with the function `add_something`

```
function add_something(){
    //logic
}
```

Then in the front end, you should be using the `ajaxurl` global variable supplied by Wordpress.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: { 
        action: 'add_something', //this was defined earlier
        data: 'other data here'
    },
    success: function(data){
        //do whatever with the callback
    }
});
```

This negates the need to explicitly declare any URL, and as such, is the proper way to perform ajax calls in Wordpress.

Comment: Be careful, `wp_ajax_yourfunc` will only work for logged-in users. Make sure to use both `wp_ajax_yourfunc` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_yourfunc` to make the ajax call work for both guests and logged-in users. Also you forgot to mention that the JavaScript variable `ajaxurl` must be set in PHP to `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');` otherwise it will not work. Cheers!