# How do I send a variable name and its value to the server and receive back a calculated response

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, server

I am new to wordpress and plugins but have a reasonable grip on php, javascript and html. I have created a plugin for wordpress which generates a page (form) which gathers information regarding a product specification. [It is actually a number of sequential forms, but for simplicity lets say it is one.  I do not want to "submit" the form as there are many fields on each form and I do not want to "submit" until it is completed and they are ready to move to the next form].

I would like to be able to (re)calculate the product price when the user changes a parameter. To do this I would like to be able to pass the name of the changed parameter and its value back to the server (where all of the dependant data for the calculation is stored), and do the calculation and return the new price. At present I have a javascript function which is called with the pertinent data on an "onChange" and then modifies the div which represents the total price. this works if I compute the value locally, but now I am looking to complete the function by sending data to the server and receiving the calculated response e.g. :

```
function total_price(arg,value) {

   ***** send arg and value to server *****

   ***** receive total_price back from server *****

    var total_div = document.getElementById("total_price");
    total_div.innerHTML = "&pound;"+total_price;
}
```

What code should I be putting in here and what should I have on the server in order to receive the data, do the calculation and send back the result?

Comment: See: XmlHttpRequest to make request and update page in its response event handler  (aka AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

I mostly have jQuery loaded in the front-end, so I'll post an answer using the jQuery framework. You'll most probably find a good vanilla snippet elsewhere if you're not looking to load a javascript library.

## Front End

```
var html_price = 1; // Whatever you need here

// You'll notice that the ajaxurl variable below, is sent to the front-end in the second code snippet of this answer
$.post( ajaxurl, {
    action: "get_total_price", // action is a special parameter Wordpress is listening for
    price: html_price
}).done( function( price ) {
    // Price back from the server you can use in the DOM
    // You should probably send this using JSON, this example only uses a string
    console.log( price ); 
});
```

## Back End

```
// Here is where Wordpress is waiting for that special action parameter
// https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_total_price', 'get_total_price' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_total_price', 'get_total_price' );    

function get_total_price() {
    $price = $_POST[ 'price' ];

    if( $price ) {

        // do with the price what you want
        echo $price; // Echo instead of return
        exit; // Remember to close up the server response here

    } else {

        echo '0'; // Unrealistic, but guarantees a response
        exit;

    }
}

// Send the AJAX URL to the front end. There are more elegant ways to do this, but for the purpose of this answer, this should work.
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ajaxurl_to_head' );
function add_ajaxurl_to_head() { ?>
    <script>
        ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    </script>
<?php }
```

Comment: Also a great, more in-depth answer covering a similar question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259241/proper-way-to-link-ajax-url

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now have:

Comment: Thanks, this worked (after a few amendments to accommodate wordpress), but I need to change form jquery.post to jquery.ajax to use the extended arguments of jquery.ajax. I have tried replacing:

Comment: Thanks, this partially worked, but I need to change form jquery.post to jquery.ajax. I have tried replacing:

    jQuery.post( ajaxurl,  {
        action: "ghmp",
        arg: hw_arg,
        val: hw_value
    }).done (function( hw_total ) {
        hardware_div.innerHTML = hw_total;
    });

with

    jQuery.ajax( ajaxurl, {
        type: "POST",
        success: "ghmp",
        arg: hw_arg,
        val: hw_value
    }).done (function( hw_total ) {
         hardware_div.innerHTML = hw_total;
    });

But the function ghmp never gets called!

Comment: Hmm. How do I put code on a comment without it getting garbled?

Answer (score 0):

At last I got it working (based upon your code and grasping the difference between the server and client contexts, which language to use where and what data is accessible). Thanks for your help. There must be scope for a single language for web development which is readable and context aware? HeHo, there I go wanting the world to change to suit me!!